# Can not parse time string with pd.to_datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Not able to parse a date string into a Pandas date.

I have tried various formats for the date, however, I can't figure out a way to easily debug it as opposed to guessing.

test = pd.to_datetime('Thu Mar 21 18:24:35 +0000 2019', format=('%A %B %d %H:%M:%S','+0000', '%Y'))

ValueError: time data 'Thu Mar 21 18:24:35 +0000 2019' doesn't match format specified

Comment: if you don't bother adding a `format`, this works fine.

Comment: I get AssertionError: when removing format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For certain versions of pandas (I tested with 0.24.1), it should work without specifying format:

```
test = pd.to_datetime('Thu Mar 21 18:24:35 +0000 2019')
```

There are, however, issues with your format string. For one, I'm not sure why you're provided a tuple rather than one continuous string. For two, you use `'%A'` and `%B'` - in datetime formatting, these provide the weekday and month as the full name in both cases ([source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)). In your case, you have the abbreviated names - `'%a'` and `'%b'`. So the following should work:

```
test = pd.to_datetime('Thu Mar 21 18:24:35 +0000 2019', format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
```